# Why isn't my code printing anything while I am attempting to reverse the words in a string

Tags: java, string, reverse

Given a string: "This is a test"

I wrote a program to reverse the words in the string, so I get an output of: "test a is this"

This is my code in java:

```
public class stringreversals {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String str = "This is a test";
        System.out.println(str);
        reverseWordInAString(str);
        System.out.println(str);
    }
static void reverseWordInAString(String str){
    char[] array = str.toCharArray();
    int length = array.length;
    reverseString(array, 0, length-1);
    int i=0, start=0;
    while(i<=length){
        if(array[i]!=' '){
            i++;
        }
        else{
            reverseString(array, start, i-1);
            start = i+1;
        }
    }
    }
static void reverseString(char[] array, int start, int end){
    int i=0, j=0;
    char c;
    for(i = start, j =end; i< j; i++, j--){
        c = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = c;

    }
  }
}
```

Every time I run it, it just prints the first string, but doesn't print the second one for some reason.

Comment: Strings are immutable, so `str` will always stay the same within `main()`.

Comment: The `else` within your `while` causes it to loop forever. You never modify `i`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You're actually right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few notable issues, the first is with your `while-loop` in the `reverseWordInAString(String)` method...

```
while(i<=length){
    if(array[i]!=' '){
        i++;
    }
    else{
        reverseString(array, start, i-1);
        start = i+1;
    }
}
```

This loop will result in an infinite loop, because when you detect a space, you never increment the `i`, meaning that it's always stuck on the space character

We can fix this by always incrementing the `i` value on each loop, for example...

```
    while (i <= length) {
        if (array[i] == ' ') {
            reverseString(array, start, i - 1);
            start = i + 1;
        }
        i++;
    }
```

But wait, now we're getting an `IndexOutOfRange` exception.  This is cause by the fact that arrays are `0` indexed in Java (the first element is `0`), but we're allowing the loop to run until `i` == `length` (but the indexable range is `length - 1`)

We can fix this by doing something like...

```
    while (i < length) {
        if (array[i] == ' ') {
            reverseString(array, start, i - 1);
            start = i + 1;
        }
        i++;
    }
```

This outputs `test a is sihT` ... Okay, but the last word is not reversed...

This is because when the loop exists, we've not actually reversed the word...

We can fix this by adding something like...

```
if (start < i) {
    reverseString(array, start, i - 1);
}
```

after the `while-loop` has exited...

But this still isn't going to show the `String` in the `main` method, to do that, we need to return the result of the reversal from the method...

```
static String reverseWordInAString(String str) {
    char[] array = str.toCharArray();
    int length = array.length;
    reverseString(array, 0, length - 1);
    int i = 0, start = 0;
    while (i < length) {
        if (array[i] == ' ') {
            reverseString(array, start, i - 1);
            start = i + 1;
        }
        i++;
    }

    if (start < i) {
        reverseString(array, start, i - 1);
    }
    return new String(array);
}
```

And then assign the result back to a variable from the calling method...

```
str = reverseWordInAString(str);
System.out.println(str);
```

Now, having said all that, you could simply use `String#split` and pass it `" "` (empty space), which will return all the `String` elements within an array split on the space, you could use the same technique you used for reversing the original `String` to reverse the positions of each word...saving yourself some time and hassle...but that's me...

Comment: your answer was perfect, this code runs in O(n) with O(1) space, this is the most efficient it would get to, right?

Comment: @Ralphyabro I have no idea of the efficiency, given that you reverse the whole `String` and the reverse each word AGAIN, I doubt it's the most efficient means I could think of...as evident with my comment at the end... ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning the new generated String.

You should change your method signature:

> static **String** reverseWordInAString(String str)

add this to the end of the method

```
return new String(array);
```

and change this

```
reverseWordInAString(str);
System.out.println(str);
```

for this

```
System.out.println(reverseWordInAString(str));
```

**EDIT:**

You have an error in your implementation, replace your while with this code and it should work now.

```
    // just use less than (not equal)
    while(i<length){
        // check for a space to reverse the word
        if(array[i]==' '){
            reverseString(array, start, i-1);
            start = i+1;
        }
        // increment i always
        i++;
    }
    // reverse the last word
    reverseString(array, start, length - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix your code, try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String str = "This is a test";
    System.out.println(str);
    String reversed = reverseWordInAString(str);
    System.out.println(reversed);
}

static string reverseWordInAString(String str) {
    char[] array = str.toCharArray();
    ...
    return new String(array);
}
```

Strings are immutable but arrays of characters are not, so the rest of the code looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything with str.
change your reverseWordInAString signature to

```
static String reverseWordInAString(String str){
    char[] array = str.toCharArray();
    int length = array.length;
    reverseString(array, 0, length-1);
    int i=0, start=0;
    while(i<=length){
        if(array[i]!=' '){
            i++;
        }
        else{
            reverseString(array, start, i-1);
            start = i+1;
        }
    }
    return Arrays.toString(array);
}
```

and then

```
 str = reverseWordInAString(str);
 System.out.println(str);
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    String str = "This is a test";
    String[] wordArray = str.split(" ");
    String reversedStr = "";
    for(int i =wordArray.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
        reversedStr += wordArray[i];
    }
    System.out.println("reversedStr: " + reversedStr);
```